# apache redirect whatever.domain1.com to whatever.domain2.com

Tags: apache-http-server, redirection

I'm trying to redirect from whatever.domain1.com to whatever.domain2.com, but it has to work for any value of 'whatever'. I have tried the following

```
<VirtualHost <PUBLIC_IP_ADDR>:80>
    ServerName  domain1.com
    ServerAlias *.domain1.com

    RewriteEngine On    
    SetEnvIf Host "(.*).domain1.com" VHOST=$1
    # http replaced with xxxx as otherwise im not allowed to post
    RewriteRule .* xxxx://%{VHOST}.domain2.com [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

however, this does not work, i.e. VHOST variable is always empty. Is there any other way to either manipulate the HTTP Host: header and/or use only a part of it in a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

one can use backreferences from RewriteCond regexp match

```
   ServerName  domain1.com
   ServerAlias *.domain1.com

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^(.*).domain1.com$"
   RewriteRule .* xxxx://%1.domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [R,L]
```